# How can I retrieve a comma-separate list of linked ids in a 3-way MYSQL join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm creating a book tagging system (i'm sure this has been done tons of times before), and I'd like to create a `view` that gives me each book, with its `tags`' names.

**I have three tables:**

1. books ( id, name)
2. tags (id, name)
3. bookTags (id, book, tag)

**And I'd like to have one view**

1. booksInfo (books.id, books.name, [comma-separated-`tags.name`s], [tagids])

With my current `view` (in the sql fiddle below), I get duplicate rows, one for each tag-book pair.

I'd love to get something like this:

```
   BOOKID          NAME            TAGS                    TAGIDS
   ------          -----------     --------------------    ---------
     1             1984            Dystopian, Political      3, 4
     2             White Fang      Dogs, Nature              5, 9
     3             Bible           Religion, History         6, 10
     4             1776            Political, History        4, 10
```

I created a sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74b57/1/0

I could do this with PHP after my select, then go through it and create a separate array, but that seems unnecessary. I find with MySQL there's almost always a query-way to do something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` with `GROUP BY`

```
select 
    b.id 'id',
    b.name 'name',
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) 'tag',
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.id) 'tagid'
from
    bookTags bt
        left join
    books b ON b.id = bt.book
        left join
    tags t ON t.id = bt.tag
GROUP BY bt.book;
```

**Result for your fiddle**

```
+------+------------------+------------------+-------+
| id   | name             | tag              | tagid |
+------+------------------+------------------+-------+
|    1 | 1984             | Government       | 2     |
|    2 | Huckelberry Finn | Adventure        | 1     |
|    3 | The bible        | Religion         | 3     |
|    4 | White Fang       | Adventure,Nature | 1,4   |
+------+------------------+------------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Thank you very much! I'll accept your answer as the clearest

Answer (score 2):

Check

```
create view booksInfo as
select 
b.id 'id',
b.name as 'name',
GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) as 'tag',
GROUP_CONCAT(t.id) 'tagid'
from bookTags bt
left join books b
on b.id = bt.book
left join tags t
on t.id = bt.tag
group by bt.book;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68cdd/1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `group_concat` function to transform a series of values on different rows to a coma delimited values:

```
SELECT    b.id AS book_id, b.name AS book_name, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) AS tags, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(t.id) AS tag_ids
FROM      bookTags bt
LEFT JOIN books b ON b.id = bt.book
LEFT JOIN tags t  ON t.id = bt.tag
GROUP BY  b.id, b.name
```

Answer (score 1):

**GROUP_CONCAT(exp) Function is Dedicated for the comma separated**

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

> SELECT  b.id 'id',b.name 'name',
>
> GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) 'tag',
>
> GROUP_CONCAT(t.id) 'tagid'
>
> FROM
>
> bookTags bt
>
> LEFT JOIN
>
> books b ON (b.id = bt.book)
>
> LEFT JOIN
>
> tags t ON (t.id = bt.tag) GROUP BY bt.book;

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't manipulate your results in your query. It would be much nicer to return your list with duplicates and roll up on ID.

```
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
  $out[$row['id']]['id'] = $row['id'];
  $out[$row['id']]['name'] = $row['name'];
  $out[$row['id']]['tags'] .= ', '.$row['tags'];
  $out[$row['id']]['tagids'] = ', '.$row['name'];
}
```

This is only quick, but you could roll this up into a nice little function that didn't reference keys directly, didn't repeat commas etc etc etc. (i.e. this is really ugly code and I apologise).

But the moment you try and scale a large amount of data with groups, you'll have another problem to solve.